# Unable to connect mongodb using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

**i am trying the following code to create a new DB but it dosen't show up in my MongoDB localhost connection. I used the callback function and it returned no error.**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/personDB", { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true });
```

Comment: A database wont showup in terminal unless and until you create at least one collection and add document to it. So if you have any schemas in your code, export it as a mongoose model and perform an insert operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add error in you question. I think this is enough. Check whether mongodb is running fine.

Try this

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true
})

mongoose.connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log("Connected")
})
```